# Two DIVs side-by-side

Tags: html

There are two DIVs in my HTML code and they are not nested. I want to display the images in these DIVs side-by-side. First DIV on the left and the second on the right.

Comment: What is the problem/question?

Comment: @Felix: I don't want to use CSS.

Comment: You don't want to use CSS? What, why? Do you understand what CSS is?

Comment: @Tatu: Yes I know. Stylesheets to give more control on the design.

Comment: Seriously, you should get used to using CSS. It makes life so much easier. The solution below (with the `style` attributes) is just CSS inside the tags (which is normally ill-advised, but the only way to do it without CSS).

Comment: @RPK: Without CSS, you cannot show DIVs side by side. Sorry.

Comment: Sure guys. I am working on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="float:left">First Image Here</div>
<div style="float:left">Second Image Here</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
div.yourDivClassName { display:inline; }
```